# Can I pass a type as a parameter to this function?

Tags: types, f#, polymorphism, parametric-polymorphism, static-polymorphism

The following code, mostly copied from

http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_MachineLearning_VectorMachines_Learning_SequentialMinimalOptimization.htm

works fine.

```
module SVMModule

open Accord.MachineLearning
open Accord.MachineLearning.VectorMachines
open Accord.MachineLearning.VectorMachines.Learning
open Accord.Statistics.Kernels
open Accord.Math.Optimization.Losses

// open MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Matrix

let inputs = [| [| 0.; 0. |]; [| 0.; 1. |]; [| 1.; 0. |]; [| 1.; 1. |] |]
let xor = [| 0; 1; 1; 0 |]
/// Creates and trains a Support Vector Machine given inputs and outputs.
/// The kernel can be Linear, Gaussian, or Polynomial.
/// The default tolerance is 1e-2.
let train (C: float) (tol: float) (inputs: float [] []) =
    let learn = SequentialMinimalOptimization<Gaussian>()

    learn.UseComplexityHeuristic <- true
    learn.UseKernelEstimation <- true
    if C >= 0. then learn.Complexity <- C
    if tol > 0. then learn.Tolerance <- tol

    let svm = learn.Learn(inputs, xor)
    svm

let svm = train 0.5 1e-2 inputs
let prediction = svm.Decide inputs

printfn "SVM_0 Prediction: %A" prediction
```

I would like to implement a polymorphic version of `train`, something like

```
let train (kernel: string) (C: float) (tol: float) (inputs: float [] []) =
    let learn =
        if kernel = "Gaussian" then 
           SequentialMinimalOptimization<Gaussian>()
        else
           SequentialMinimalOptimization<Linear>()
    // More code
```

This does not work because an `if` expression must return objects of the same type in all its branches.

I wonder if there is a way to pass `Linear` or `Gaussian` as a type to `train` (these are indeed types) so that I do not have to write one train function for each type (`trainGaussian` and `trainLinear`). Akso, even if I took the trouble of writing these separate functions, I guess it would be difficult to call them at runtime depending on a user choice, as the same problem with an `if` statement would rear its ugly head.

I have implemented polymorphism in `F#` using interfaces, but with classes I built myself. These classes are in `Accord.NET` and even though they inherit from a base class I was not able to handle the type issue and implement polymorphism.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be straightforward to simply replace the concrete type `Gaussian` with a type parameter like `'t` (and, optionally, add it as an explicit type parameter to `train`).  I've cleaned up your existing code very slightly while doing so:

```
let train<'t> (C: float) (tol: float) (inputs: float [] []) =
    let learn = SequentialMinimalOptimization<'t>(UseComplexityHeuristic = true, UseKernelEstimation = true)
    if C >= 0. then learn.Complexity <- C
    if tol > 0. then learn.Tolerance <- tol

    learn.Learn(inputs, xor)
```

Then at the call-site, there will need to be some way for the compiler to know what type to use, either by passing it in explicitly:

```
let svm = train<Gaussian> 0.5 1e-2 inputs
```

or by relying on type inference to flow the types from another part of your program:

```
let svm:Gaussian = train 0.5 1e-2 inputs
```

Comment: Thanks. That looks promising. However, when I copied your code into my .fsx file I got a red squiggly line under SequentialMinimalOptimization<'t> and the message `A type parameter is missing a constraint 'when 't :> IKernel<float []>'`. Am I still missing something?

Comment: @Soldalma - sorry, I guess there's a constraint on `SequentialMinimalOptimization<_>`'s type parameter, which you'll need to include in your definition if you add an explicit type parameter (i.e. you need to define it as `train<'t when 't :> IKernel<float []>>`).  On the other hand, if you omit the parameter from the definition (so it's just `let train (C:float) ...`) then I believe the constraint should be inferred without any additional work on your part.

Comment: Thanks again. Both alternatives work, although I am surprised that you can remove the type from the function signature and leave it in the function body. Moving on, I met another obstacle. If the type is Linear the statement `learn.UseKernelEstimation <- true` leads to a runtime error. Is there a way to skip it using an `if` or `match` statement  that depends on the type?